# How to parse xml using c# dom but not using linqToXml?

Tags: c#, xml, dom

This is my xml

```
<Placemark>
    <name>KOTAK ABC SCHOOL</name>
    <address>KOTAK ABC SCHOOL,Pincode-00000</address>
    <styleUrl>#icon-1899-0288D1</styleUrl>
    <ExtendedData>
        <Data name="School Address">
            <value>KOTAK ABC SCHOOL,</value>
        </Data>
        <Data name="unnamed (1)">
        </Data>
        <Data name="coordinates">
        </Data>
        <Data name="unnamed (2)">
        </Data>
        <Data name="unnamed (3)">
        </Data>
    </ExtendedData>
    <MultiGeometry>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>83.334596,17.744104,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
        <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>
                83.32842825758384,17.71897819318788,0 83.32842825758384,17.72522980681212,0 83.33676374241615,17.72522980681212,0 83.33676374241615,17.71897819318788,0 83.32842825758384,17.71897819318788,0 
            </coordinates>
        </LinearRing>
    </MultiGeometry>
</Placemark>
```

I Want to get the name and coordinates inside the tag MultiGeometry\Point

```
XmlDataDocument xmldoc = new XmlDataDocument();
XmlNodeList xmlnode;
FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\\Schools.xml", FileMode.Open,  FileAccess.Read);
xmldoc.Load(fs);
xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Placemark");
foreach ()  ?
```

can i travers using foreach method to the inner node? i can only use the c# dom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
XmlDataDocument xmldoc = new XmlDataDocument();
FileStream fs = new FileStream("test.xml", FileMode.Open,  FileAccess.Read);
xmldoc.Load(fs);
XmlNodeList _ngroups = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Placemark");
foreach(XmlNode nd in _ngroups)
{
Console.WriteLine(nd.ChildNodes[4].ChildNodes[0].InnerText.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(nd.ChildNodes[4].ChildNodes[1].InnerText.ToString());
}
```

OR

```
XmlNodeList _ngroups = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Placemark");
foreach(XmlNode nd in _ngroups)
{
if(nd.ChildNodes[nd.ChildNodes.Count-1].Name=="MultiGeometry")
{
Console.WriteLine(nd.ChildNodes[nd.ChildNodes.Count-1].ChildNodes[0].InnerText.ToString());
}
    if(nd.ChildNodes[nd.ChildNodes.Count-1].ChildNodes[1].Name=="LinearRing")
{
Console.WriteLine(nd.ChildNodes[nd.ChildNodes.Count-1].ChildNodes[1].InnerText.ToString());
}
```

Comment: giving system.NullRefrenceException

Comment: still that exception persist!

Comment: This should work. Are you using right file (`test.xml` or `c:\\schools.xml`)? What error are you getting? On which line?

Comment: Answer looks correct. please debug and check what error are you getting?

Comment: You may have problem with the location of file "C:\\Schools.xml"

Comment: no i change the location and all but giving the exception.. i try to debug still it is not navigating to inner node

Comment: When you open your xml with internet web browser is it showing content properly? I mean you may have errors in your xml file.

Comment: I is "MultiGeometry" debug and find :) it is not that much science fiction I guess.